# Display autocomplete strings as editable tokens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I need to make each strings look like tokens using css. Like a gmail functionality after the selection by the user.

If I select **Someone <someone@example.com>** it should appear like token for string **Someone** only and not for whole. but when I double click the token it should expand and editable as **Someone <someone@example.com>**

I had to work with,

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];

  function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
  }

  function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  }

  $("#tags")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .on("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    })
    .autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: function(request, response) {
        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
          availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
      },
      focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join(", ");
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```